# How can a PDF fallback font be specified in knitr?

Tags: r, pdf, knitr

When working with R Markdown files, is there a way to specify multiple `mainfont` options, allowing `knitr` to fall back to fonts when the first choice is not available?

Current sample YAML header:

```
---
title: "Super Fancy Report"
mainfont: BentonSansRE
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
    fig_caption: yes
    toc: yes
  html_notebook:
    code_folding: hide
    css: html-styles.css
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 3
    toc_float: yes
---
```

I'd like to do something like (non-functional example):

```
---
title: "Super Fancy Report"
mainfont:
- BentonSansRE
- Arial Narrow
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
    fig_caption: yes
    toc: yes
  html_notebook:
    code_folding: hide
    css: html-styles.css
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 3
    toc_float: yes
---
```